# Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop React Native with FlatList render

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I don't understand why I get this error, when rendering screen I use useSelector to get state from store(I'm using redux) I get data from api and pass it to flatList to render the list, everything is normal but I don't know why

```
const HistoryScreen = () => {


    const { loading, histories } = useSelector((state) => state.historiesList)

    useEffect(() => {

        if (user) {
            dispatch(listHistory())
        }
    }, [dispatch, user])

    return (

            <FlatList data={histories} renderItem={({ item, i }) => <HistoryCard key={i} onPress={() => console.warn('cliecked')} post={item} ></HistoryCard>}>
            </FlatList >
        </View >}</>
    )
}

export default HistoryScreen
```

action:

```
export const listHistory = (skip = 0, limit = 10) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {

        dispatch({ type: HISTORY_LIST_REQUEST })
        const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userInfo')
        const userInfo = user ? JSON.parse(user) : null

        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`
            }
        }

        const payload = { skip: skip, limit: limit }
        const { data } = await axios.post(`${api}/histories/`, payload, config)

        dispatch({ type: HISTORY_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data.data })
        console.log(data.data)

    } catch (error) {

        dispatch({ type: HISTORY_LIST_FAILED, payload: error })
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your dispatch look like? If it's getting updated every time then you might wanna add it to a ref or useState

Comment: It is dispatch `const dispatch = useDispatch();`

Comment: it is action `export const listHistory = (skip = 0, limit = 10) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {

        dispatch({ type: HISTORY_LIST_REQUEST })

        const config = {
            ....
            }
        }

        const payload = { skip: skip, limit: limit }
        const { data } = await axios.post(`${api}/histories/`, payload, config)

        dispatch({ type: HISTORY_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data.data })

    } catch (error) {

        dispatch({ type: HISTORY_LIST_FAILED, payload: error })
    }
}`

Comment: Edit that into your question

Comment: I have edited in question